# Rewrite Specific PHP file to directory with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So I have a URL that is domain.com/s_cart.php?&pid=1 and /s_cart.php?&gid=2

How would i go about setting a .htaccess to rewrite s_cart.php to the following

domain.com/order/&pid=1

Tried the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/order([/]*)$ ./s_cart.php?gid=5 [L,NC]
```

Didn't work.

Basically I'm trying to add domain.com/order?pid=1

When the actual url currently is domain.com/s_cart.php?pid=1

Comment: You also could redirect all requests to a _front controller_, as do the frameworks. So your URL could be what you want, and you would be able to add URIs in the future, the work wouldn't be in .htaccess but in your PHP.

Comment: Please share what you tried so far and what errors you encountered, read also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yeah, we're using WHMCS and made our own order form script, Just want to redirect the s_cart.php to /order to look nicer.

Comment: We've tried this, but it didn't work.

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/order([/]*)$ ./s_cart.php?gid=5 [L,NC]

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question to include all relevant code.

Comment: Still at a loss, unable to find anything out.